# Can't log in to Django-Admin but can log in with custom form

Tags: django

In a recent code change I am no longer able to log in through /admin/ or my default login page, but I can log in using a page that redirects to the login page. The redirect in question:

```
def show_calendar(request):
    user = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'error': 'Email and password not recognised. Please try again.'})
    if request.user.is_authenticated or user:
        return render(request, 'calendar/full_calendar.html', {})
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {})
```

The above view works when authenticating like that. However, when logging in via my login page or /admin/ I get some logs from within `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` and it seems to always be hitting `This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.`:

```
def authenticate(**credentials):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """
    for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
        logging.debug(credentials)
        try:
            inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, **credentials)
        except TypeError:
            logging.debug("This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.")
            # This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.
            continue
```

`credentials` logs as: `DEBUG:root:{'password': 'pass', 'username': 'admin@admin.com'}`

Relevant **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'fullcalendar',
    'crispy_forms',
    'autoslug',
    'storages',
    'boto',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'updown',
    'stream_django',
    'postman',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['myapp.CustomBackend.CustomBackend',]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

`myapp.User` has its `USERNAME_FIELD` set to `email`

**CustomBackend.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

from myapp.models import User
from myapp import settings
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)


class CustomBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        user = None
        logging.debug("CUSTOM BACKEND AUTHENTICATE AUTHENTICATE")
        try:
            valid_user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if valid_user.check_password(password):
                user = valid_user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return user


    def authenticate(self, email, password):
        user = None
        logging.debug("AUTHENTICATE")
        try:
            valid_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if valid_user.check_password(password):
                user = valid_user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I have been unable to pin down the exact code change that caused this issue. The only difference is that I'm passing `username` and `password` in the default login page and the admin page whereas in my view I'm fetching the `email` and `password`. Surely the `def authenticate(self, username, password):` method should be correctly utilised, but according to my logs it is never hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you expect the correct `authenticate` method to be chosen based on the arguments. However, in Python, your second `authenticate(self, email, password)` method *replaces* the first one `authenticate(self, username, password):`.

It's not clear to my why you have created a custom authentication backend. Since you have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` in your custom user model, the default model backend should work ok with the default login page.

In your custom views, change the code to `authenticate(username=email, password=password)`. However, I would avoid writing views that log users in where possible, to avoid mistakes or possible security holes.

Rather than handling logins in the `show_calendar` view, I would use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator instead. Anonymous users will be redirected to the login page, then redirected back to the view once they have logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def show_calendar(request):
    return render(request, 'calendar/full_calendar.html', {})
```

Comment: Saved my ass yet again. Will accept when I can. Thanks for the extra info

Answer (score 0):

Under the WEB tab in your pythonanywhere login , just check the wsgi configuration file.
A sample for reference is as shown below:

```
import os
import sys
path='/home/invinciblycool/my-first-blog/'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']= 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```